# Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool

Tags: windows

I'd like to download `Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool`, but I've tried to search google and only get the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=5124

It's hidden into SDK download link

[image]